# Is it possible for Xcode 6 to display errors for iOS 7 compatibility?

Tags: ios, xcode, backwards-compatibility

I have Xcode 6 and the game I am writing crashes when I run it in the iOS7 simulator.

Yes, I can read the logs during runtime such as [SKEmitterNode nodeWithFileNamed:] doesn't exist in iOS 7. But it would be much nicer to see that this method doesn't exist when I'm typing it (also without having to look at the developers documentation) since I learned Sprite Kit on iOS 8.

I know you can do this if you change the SDK to iOS 7, but I've read numerous problems happens if you rig the project like that. Is there any other way to get errors or warning before runtime?

Comment: Other than respondstoselector, I don't think there are any active compile check to see if the method exist or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application [DeployMate](http://www.deploymateapp.com) is made for exactly this purpose.

Comment: Do you have any other free app or opensource app?